# Populate HTML Form with Livesearch Selection

Tags: php, jquery

Have a working livesearch function that is working fine when terms are entered, the code is shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#keyword').on('input', function() {
    var searchKeyword = $(this).val();
    if (searchKeyword.length >= 3) {
        $.post('holdersearch.php', { keywords: searchKeyword }, function(data) {
        $('ul#liveSearchList').empty()
        $.each(data, function() {
        $('ul#liveSearchList').append('<span class="searchResultItem">
           <a href="?hldr=' + this.id + '">' + this.holder + ' 
           </a></span></br>'); 
        });
        }, "json").fail($('ul#liveSearchList').empty());
    } else {
        $('ul#liveSearchList').empty()
    };
});
});
```

This creates a list under the input field shown in the code below, what I would like to do is populate the input field as shown below:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" size="100%" placeholder="Enter Holder name Here" id="keyword" name="pmntHolder"/>
<ul id="liveSearchList"></ul>
```

This has me completely baffled on how to achieve it, i can't figure out how to manipulate the link to populate the input field with the holder name. The list created is shown below.

**Edit ** I have tried adding the following JQuery, however it doesn't populate the input box:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.searchResultItem').on('click', function() {
        var holderName = $(this).find("a").text();
        $('#keyword').val(holderName);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: What is this `$('#keyword').$('searchResultItem');`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on `$('.searchResultItem');` you should take text of the element you clicked on and pass it to your `$('#keyword')` via `val`-function:

```
$('.searchResultItem').on('click', function() {
    // find a-tag in .searchResultItem item and get it's text
    var clickedValue = $( this ).find( "a" ).text();
    // pass founded value to your input
    $('#keyword').val( clickedValue );
});
```

Comment: Have updated my code with your suggestion, unfortunately still getting no entry in the input field, firebug console is not giving any errors either.

Comment: My mistake. try `html()` instead ot `text()`.

Comment: No problem, have changed that, but still no output. I've put `console.log("Holder: ",holderName);` after the `var holderName` line and checked the console, there is no output at all for it so it makes me wonder if the click even isn't occuring??

Comment: Maybe `$( ".searchResultItem a" ).on( "click" ... )` is better option?

Comment: Unfortunately still no go. Don't know if it makes a difference but the input field I'm trying to populate is the one the keywords are being typed into.

Comment: Check fpr z-order of your elements. Maybe click doesn't happen because elements are behind something else.

Comment: Getting somewhere now - well sort of. The console log is now showing the holder name, so the click is working, the input field is still not being populated BUT I think I now have bigger problems in that the console.log is only ever showing the first name on the list even if I click on the second, third names etc.

Comment: I think I'm going nuts here, it is now populating the input field - yay, but is only ever taking the first selection in the list. However you've fixed the problem I asked about in this question so will mark it as answered and thank you VERY much for your help :).